# What is the zero in a ring of functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If we're given a ring, $R$, which is a collection of functions, say $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that follow the ring axioms. What is the zero of this ring? Is it the regular $0$ from $\mathbb R$ or is it the group of elements whose output is $0$ from $\mathbb R$. Also, same question but for the $1$ of the ring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it must be a function since elements of this ring are functions.  So, it is the function which is constantly $0$.

Comment: Wouldn't the definition of the identity and zero element usually be part of the definition of the ring of functions?

Answer (score 1):

The elements of this collection are functions, so the zero and one element must also be functions.

The zero element is the one which, for all $a \in R$, $a + 0 = a$. So if $a: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary function, what function $z: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ will make $a(x) + z(x) = a(x)$ true?

Similarly, the one element is the one which makes $1 \times a = a$ true, so what function $y: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ will make $y(x) a(x) = a(x)$ always true?